# What role did the second lightsaber play in Rey's final fight?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In the final fight of Rey in *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*, she is in the following situation:

> Rey heard the voices of all the dead Jedi. They are all "with her". She stands up and confronts Palpatine again, with one lightsaber. Palpatine shoots his lightning at her, she defends herself against it with her lightsaber. Palpatine is still confident that he is winning, and it seems that Rey can barely deflect the lightning and slowly loses ground. Then Palpatine says he is "all Sith." Rey answers, that she is "all Jedi," calling the second lightsaber to her other hand. She lights the second lightsaber and suddenly, with both sabers she is able to easily deflect the lightning back to Palpatine in a manner that destroys him (and the whole building.) I think it's clear, that it was not the second lightsaber that changed her odds from "no chance to win" to "easily defeated" but what changes the odds was that all dead Jedi where with her and she countered the force of "all Sith" no longer only with the force of Rey but with the force of "all Jedi".

Why did she bother calling the second lightsaber and what role did it play in the final defeat? Was the second lightsaber needed? Wouldn't she be able to win without the second lightsaber even if

> all Jedi are with her?

Comment: This will be explained in Episode X: Chewbacca does the Electric Boogaloo.

Comment: The second lightsaber gave a sensitive performance in the role of The Dauphin.

Answer (score 2):

## It's a trope

[Rule of Cool:](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool)

> The limit of the Willing Suspension of Disbelief for a given element is directly proportional to its awesomeness.
>
> Stated another way, all but the most pedantic of viewers will forgive liberties with reality as long as the result is wicked sweet or awesome. (....) Also known in some circles as a "rad herring", in which something doesn't make sense within the guidelines of the story's reality, but it's too cool not to include it.
>
> (...)
>
> There are no instances of this trope being justified, nor can there be — after all, the entire point is that it's about things that don't make sense but we still gladly accept just because they're cool.

Someone once said that if you extract the actual plot from some Star Wars movies the text would fit into the back of a postage stamp. Seems to be the case of Episode IX, in which the heroes have to get one thing so they can get another thing in order to finally confront the villain. A lot of what we see in the screen is basically fillers, so in order to make it enjoyable Disney abused the Rule of Cool.